# How to convert DOM::MATRIX to Function

Tags: matlab, mupad

A simple example of what I am doing is as follows:

```
s := t*0.2:
b := matrix([0.5,0.6,0.1]):
f := matrix([sin(s),cos(s),s]):
X := transpose(b)*(f);
plotfunc2d(X,t=-2*PI..2*PI);
```

The error is:

`Error: Expecting an arithmetical expression or a function. Got a 'Dom::Matrix()' for attribute 'Function' in the 'Function2d' object.`

so, I need to convert types from `Dom::Matrix` to `Function`. I have tried:

```
coerce(X,DOM_EXPR);
```

I know that simply, this works:

```
s := t*0.2:
x := 0.5*sin(s)+0.6*cos(s)+0.1*s;
plotfunc2d(x,t=-2*PI..2*PI);
```

Is there a way to convert these types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the variable `X` itself is a `DOM::Matrix()`, the single element it contains is an arithmetical expression, so you need to pass the element itself to the plot function:

```
plotfunc2d(X[1],t=-2*PI..2*PI);
```

Comment: perfect! I did not think of it.